# Comparing NSString to SQLite database field

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, sqlite, nsstring

I have these codes that retrieve value from the SQLite database and comparing it to a NSString declared in the header file.

Retrieving from database:

```
NSString *sql = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT TESTONE, TESTTWO, TESTTHREE, TESTFOUR FROM STUDENTS WHERE NAME='%@'",Name];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)== SQLITE_OK)
 {
    while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW){
        char *one = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement,0);
        tOne = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:one];
        char *two = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement,1);
        tTwo = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:two];
        char *three = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement,2);
        tThree = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:three];
        char *four = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement,3);
        tFour = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:four];
    }
 }
```

Comparing string:

```
if(tOne == @"Yes")
{
    //blablabla
}
else if(tOne == @"No")
{
    //blablabla
}
```

It doesn't seem to go into the 'IF' at all.
I have double-checked the field in the database and its TEXT datatype.
I made a UILabel to display the tOne value and it shows "Yes".

May i know what or where went wrong during the comparison?

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare strings like this, you have to use `isEqualToString:`

```
if([tOne isEqualToString:@"Yes"])
{
    //blablabla
}
else if([tOne isEqualToString:@"No"])
{
    //blablabla
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently comparing the *address* of the `NSString` object, not its contents.  Use the `compare:` or `isEqualToString:` family of methods to compare the *content* of the string.

[Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).